# Is row space of a matrix equal to the column space of the transpose of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Is row space of a matrix equal to the column space of the transpose of matrix? If yes can any one please share the proof.

Comment: Can you state the definitions of row space and column space? Then can you tell me what are the columns of the transpose of a matrix, in terms of the original matrix?

Comment: What have you written so far?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is true. This is simply because when taking the transpose of a matrix, the rows and columns swap. A bit more precisely, if $A$ is your given matrix and $A^t$ is the transpose of $A$, then the row vectors of $A$ are the same as the column vectors of $A^t$ (and analogously the column vectors of $A$ are the row vectors of $A^t$). This follows immediately from the definition of transpose. So if the row vectors of $A$ are the column vectors of $A^t$, then of course the row space of $A$ is the column space of $A^t$.

Answer (score -4):

No, this is not always true.  Here is a proof:  Let A be the two by two zero matrix.  Then the transpose of A is equal to A.  Let x be a vector in the row space of A.  Then x is a two by one matrix, and in fact it is the two by one zero matrix.  Since x is not a one by two matrix, it is not in the column space of any matrix.  Let us continue anyway, because detractors will argue that the spaces are the same because textbooks say they are, but I will explain why this is absurd.  Philosophically, their argument is called an [Appeal to Authority](https://thebestschools.org/magazine/15-logical-fallacies-know/#adverecundiam), and is fallacious.  Let us consider one of those textbooks, specifically, the [book](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/linear-algebra-and-its-applications_gilbert-strang/255319/item/3880288/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw9O6HBhCrARIsADx5qCQ3XgKx1IiM2P9ZHJoxstSxHZ9ozGcXg0pupNOQQvQEeRDZUE3Fk50aAt_gEALw_wcB#idiq=3880288&edition=2348453) by Strang called "Linear Algebra with Applications", 3rd edition, which points out on page 19 that

"As with vectors, two matrices can be added only if they have the same shape", and by "shape" is meant, as with essentially all textbooks at the same level, that the matrices in question must have the same number of rows and columns.  The same text states on that same page that vectors "can be regarded as special cases of matrices", as "matrices with only one column".

As an **aside**, I comment briefly on two foundational issues I'll disregard here:

1. the loose language used in this text is not my favorite way to present definitions and results of mathematics, because it is both philosophically and pedagogically flawed, since it is ambiguous, inexact, and formally incorrect;
2. this usage of the terminology about vectors engages a kind of abuse of terminology or notation that has a place pedagogically, but in this case, is unfortunately not accompanied by an important disclaimer about the fact that in later chapters a more general use of the word "vector" will arise, which is the more correct usage of that term.

Regarding my concerns 1 and 2, I will admit that it is not unusual among popular teachers to use less formal language, and the unfortunate common situation is that most popular teachers never make their language formal enough to properly prepare students for more advanced mathematics and the attendant cognitive load in deciphering formal language in those contexts.

One foundational issue I will not disregard is related to the axiom of extensionality in set theory, and another is the role of logical consistency in both mathematics and the pedagogy of mathematics and its applications.  The axiom of extensionality in set theory tells us when two sets are equal, and the role of logical consistency plays a role here in terms of how textbooks reflect or fail to reflect the notion of logical deduction in mathematics, which is generally viewed as formulated in a language of predicate calculus with equality, in which the usage of equal signs plays an important fundamental role that seriously impacts pedagogy, in terms of what is marked correct or incorrect in teaching, and especially in grading.  Consequently, the role that any notion of equality plays in mathematics is compounded by the cognitive load imposed upon students who are struggling with the notion of a proof in situations designed around "reward and punishment" scenarios.  In early training, they are "punished" for misusing equal signs, and later they are "rewarded" for doing so, and this is for some an insurmountable cognitive dissonance, and for all it should seem rather unfair.  But I digress.  Let us to the explanations proceed.

Thus we have established that authoritative linear algebra textbooks treat equality seriously (from the mathematical, foundational, and pedagogical perspectives all) with respect to matrices in the early chapters, because if you are asked on a test whether x=y, where x and y are matrices of different "shapes" (e.g. if x is a 2 by 1 column vector and B is a 1 by 2 row vector), then on the test you will lose points if you say "yes".  Then later in the same text, if you are asked whether y is in the column space of some matrix and you say "no", you will lose points, because x is in the column space of that particular matrix and y is equal to the transpose of x.  But the reason that the column space of a matrix is called a **column** space is that its elements are column vectors.  Thus y, being **not a column vector**, is **not equal to any column vector** at all, because **it does not have the same shape** as any column vector.  Consequently, you students are burdened with the idea that your teacher is hypocritical, or grading inconsistently, because you are awarded points for claims of equality late in the semester when the same equality claims would be punished earlier in the semester.

Pedagogically, this could be remedied by a more thorough explanation of the pedagogy from the beginning, but students who object to learning any abstraction would march to the department head and demand a different teacher if some teacher made it clear what is really happening here.

Mathematically and philosophically, we face a conundrum, because if we take the following (possibly redundant) postulates as fundamental axioms, then we can derive a contradiction in mathematics in less than two minutes, in a (fairly "small") fragment of an appropriate first order predicate calculus, with equality:

**Postulate of Equality for Matrices:**  If A is a matrix and B is a matrix and A=B, then A and B have the same number of rows and A and B have the same number of columns.  $\tag1\label1$

**Postulate of Reflexivity for Equality:**  x=x.  $\tag2\label2$

**Postulate of Membership in Row Spaces:**  If A is a matrix and r is in the row space of A, then r is a matrix with exactly one row, and the number of columns of r is the same as the number of columns of A; moreover, for every matrix A the row space of A is not the empty set.    $\tag3\label3$

**Postulate of Membership in Column Spaces:**  If A is a matrix and c is in the column space of A, then c is a matrix with exactly one column, and the number of rows of c is the same as the number of rows of A; moreover, for every matrix A the column space of A is not the empty set.  $\tag4\label4$

**Postulate of (Unidirectional) Extensionality for Classes (or Sets) of Matrices:**  If S and T are classes of matrices and S=T, then for any matrix x, if x is in S, then x is in T.  $\tag5\label5$

**Postulate of Identification  of Some Row Space with Some Column Space:**  There exist square matrices A and B with more than one row such that the row space of A is equal to the column space of B.  $\tag6\label6$

Here is the proof of a contradiction from the above postulates:
By $\eqref6$, let A and B be square matrices such that A has m>1 rows and B has n>1 rows, and the row space of A is equal to the column space of B.  By $\eqref5$, if x is in the row space of A, then x is in the column space of B. By $\eqref4$, if x is in the column space of B, then x is a matrix with exactly one column.  By logical syllogism, if x is in the row space of A, then x is a matrix with exactly one column.  By $\eqref3$, if x is in the row space of A, then x is a matrix with exactly one row.  By $\eqref2$, if x is in the row space of A, then x=x.  By $\eqref1$, x has exactly the same number of rows as x, so x has exactly one row.  By $\eqref1$ again, x has the same number of columns as x, so x has exactly one column.  Thus x is a one by one matrix, being that it is a matrix with exactly one row and exactly one column.  Application of $\eqref4$ again shows that B has exactly one row, since x has exactly one row and x is in the column space of B, i.e. n=1.  This is a contradiction.
QED

This applies to the case you asked about if you replace B with the transpose of A, as long as A has more than one row.

Comment: LOL, someone downvaoted this but does not have the guts to tell us why.

Comment: I didn't downvote your post and you raise a valid argument but you shouldn't take it so seriously. Mathematics is full of such "small ambiguities". Depending on your precise definitions, it is quite probable that a $n \times 1$ matrix or $1 \times n$ matrix is not the same as an element of $\mathbb{F}^n$ so how can you multiply a matrix by a vector? And a $1 \times 1$ matrix is not the same thing as a scalar so is the dot product $\vec{x}^T \cdot \vec{y}$ a scalar or a $1 \times 1$ matrix? And so on and so forth...

Comment: @levap, One can define the dot product of column vector x by column vector y as the determinant of x transpose times y and remove the contradiction, so that it is at least conceivable that the notion of dot product does not introduce an inconsistency into the foundations of linear algebra.  Please tell me the formal approach that you would use to remove the contradiction that I point out here.  This is by no means a "small ambiguity" when one wants to teach students and have them actually understand the mathematics for the long term.

Comment: I do not understand your question "Depending on your precise definitions, it is quite probable that a ×1 matrix or 1× matrix is not the same as an element of  so how can you multiply a matrix by a vector?"  Please clarify.

Comment: Well, what is a vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$? A formal definition in ZFC might say that a vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$ is a function $v \colon \{ 1, \dots, n \} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. What is a $n \times m$ matrix? It is a function $A \colon \{ 1, \dots, n \} \times \{ 1, \dots, m \} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. With those definitions (and assuming you believe a function is a triple which includes the domain and range), a vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$, a $n \times 1$ matrix and a $1 \times n$ matrix are three different things.

Comment: When you define multiplication of $n \times n$ matrix by a $n \times 1$ matrix, you get $n \times 1$ matrix, not a vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$. But you want to multiply matrices by vectors. So you say that you identify $n \times 1$ matrices with elements of $\mathbb{F}^n$ in the obvious way and it all works out. Similarly, you identify a $1 \times 1$ matrix with a scalar and so on and so forth. Regarding your contradiction, a formal way to remove it is to write $\textrm{Row}(A) = \textrm{Col}(A^T)^T$ where the second $T$ is the transpose isomorphism (applied to each element in the set).

Comment: And you should use the notation $\mathbb{F}^n_{\textrm{row}}$ and $\mathbb{F}^n_{\textrm{col}}$ to distinguish between row and column vectors and say that columns vectors are naturally identified with $n \times 1$ matrices and row vectors are naturally identified with $1 \times n$ matrices. This is what we do at my university.

Comment: With your comments you have helped provide evidence that, contrary to Gödel’s undecidability results, the answer to Hilbert’s question asking for a proof of the consistency of mathematics, is that mathematics is in fact inconsistent, because of the reticence of practitioners toward the efforts to repair what you call “small ambiguities”. The problem I raise is not the EXISTENCE of small ambiguities, but the absolute lack of effort to address the pedagogical consequences of such “small ambiguities” at levels of education where they make a difference.

Comment: @levap:  You wrote “Depending on your precise definitions, it is quite probable that a ×1
n
×
1
 matrix or 1×
1
×
n
 matrix is not the same as an element of 
F
n
 so how can you multiply a matrix by a vector? And a 1×1
1
×
1
 matrix is not the same thing as a scalar so is the dot product ⃗⋅⃗
x
→
T
⋅
y
→
 a scalar or a 1×1
1
×
1
 matrix? And so on and so forth”. The places where this occurs are in fundamental textbooks claiming to teach rigorous mathematics so the “depending on your definitions” part is a moot point. I’m talking about self-consistency.

Comment: @levap:  You wrote “Well, what is a vector in 
F
n
? A formal definition in ZFC ...”.  What I’m clearly getting at is that once one has chosen a system of notation and terminology, it’s anti-communicative and antithetical to the notion of good pedagogy to haphazardly violate one’s own standards without explicitly pointing out that one is abusing notation or abusing terminology.

Comment: @levap:  Giving students, in the early part of an introductory  linear algebra course, low grade because they treat a matrix and it’s transpose as being equal, but later, without clear and explicit warning, penalizing the same students because they apply what you taught them in the beginning of the course in a clearly correct and rigorous manner, is capricious. In my teaching, I endeavor to avoid such capriciousness. I either avoid abuse of notation and terminology or explain the concept of abused notation, etc, and where it arises.

Comment: @levap:  You wrote “When you define multiplication of ×
n
×
n
matrix by a ×1
n
×
1
 matrix, you get ×1
n
×
1
 matrix, not a vector in 
F
n
”.  This, as you say, depends on your definitions, and that’s really precisely my point:  those who commit the vagaries I mention are violating their own definitions, or they are naive enough to actually believe that they’re not violating their own definitions.

Comment: @levap:    You wrote “Regarding your contradiction, a formal way to remove it is to write Row()=Col()
Row
(
A
)
=
Col
(
A
T
)
T
 where the second 
T
 is the transpose isomorphism (applied to each element in the set). “. I disagree wholeheartedly with characterizing it as my contradiction.

Comment: It belongs to those who utter it as if it is fact or probable, not me. If we can as easily as you describe “remove” the contradiction, why not do so, or, at the very least, explain to the reader that one is now going to abuse notation by writing the, as you called it “less formal” version that doesn’t “remove” the contradiction. In another subject, like calculus, would you agree that saying that if f is the zero function, then it’s indefinite integral is 1?  No? ... but that’s the same “small ambiguity” you’re willing to accept, because by “is 1” here is meant “=1, up to a constant”.

Comment: Here's a related issue in calculus:  https://youtu.be/u4kex7hDC2o